# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED In AWS ECS load balancer

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have deployed a react application in AWS ECS.

My load-balancer DNS name is `rove-gui-webapp-alb-202323148.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

Inbound rules for the security group are as follows.

[image: Security group inbound rule of the load balancer]

When I try to go to the website using the DNS Name I am getting following error.

[image: Error]

Comment: How is this related to React?

Comment: Are you sure that the SSL certs have been set correctly for the load balancer?